# PFQueryTableViewController "loading" indicator stuck after successful query

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` which is properly loading data via the `queryForTable` method. Even though my tableview cells are displayed with the correct data from my query, the default parse activity indicator "loading" with the spinning wheel stays on the screen and doesn't go away. I've checked the `objectsDidLoad` method which returns no error.

Here's a simplified example of the problem with some default cells. Three cells have been loaded for a query in my database of 3 items. However, the indicator is still there for no reason.

[image: Parse PFQuery Loading]

Can anyone explain why the loading indicator continues and how to fix it?

Comment: i think you have to end it once you are done querying data from parse

Comment: I have other PFQueryTableViewControllers that work properly and I didn't have to manually end anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the "loading" alert to be removed after the objects are loaded for a PFQueryTableViewController the notification must reach the super class. You need to call `super.objectsDidLoad()` in `objectsDidLoad()` like so:

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError!) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    if error == nil {
        print("You Good")
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Don't forget to call your `super` in the future.